# Can't call functions in render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ok, so I'm trying to make a story app where you can submit a story a story, author, and title. Once you submit your story it gets stored in a google firestore. So everything works until the firestore so far. Then I want another tab which will display all the stories that are submitted. This works, wish. so I have a displayStories function that will happen in componentDidMount(), but I want to call this in side the render as shown in my code because the library of stories should keep updating. When I uncomment the displayStoies() on line 50, it throws me an error that's along the lines of "Can't setState on an unmounted component"(the warning won't show up again and it's weird). I will show my code below. Please help. :)

code:

````js
import {View,Text,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Touchable} from 'react-native'
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements'
import db from '../config.js'

export default class ReadScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = ({
            tas:[],
            storyArray:[]
        })
    }

    displayStories = async() => {
        var info = []
        var storeArray = []
        var count = 0
        //console.log("here")
        var stories = db.collection("stories").where("isStory","==","true")
        //console.log(stories)
        stories.get().then((story) => {
            //console.log("HERE")
            //console.log("Story "+story)
            story.forEach((doc) => {
                
                //console.log("HERE")
                //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
                var data = doc.data()
                info.push(data.title)
                info.push(data.author)
                //info.push(data.story)
                storeArray.push(count)
                count = count + 1
                this.setState({
                    tas:info,
                    storyCount: count,
                    storyArray: storeArray
                })
            })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.displayStories()
    }

    render() {
        //this.displayStories()
        //console.log("tas is "+this.state.tas+" there is "+this.state.storyArray+" story")
        //console.log(this.state.tas[0])
        var count = 0
        var title = "";
        var author = "";
        return(
            <View>
                <Header
                    backgroundColor = {"#b7e4c7"}
                    centerComponent = {{
                        text:"Available stories",
                        style: {
                            color:'white',
                            fontSize:20,
                            fontWeight:'bold'
                        }
                    }}/>
                {this.state.tas.map((element) => {
                    count = count + 1
                    if(count%2 == 1) {
                        title = element;
                    }
                    else {
                        author = element;
                        return(
                            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.storyButton} key = {element}>
                                <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Title: {title}</Text>
                                <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Author: {author}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                    }
                })}
                
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    AuTinput: {
        width:"80%",
        height:40,
        borderWidth:2,
        marginTop:20,
        alignSelf:'center',
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    storyInput: {
        width:"80%",
        height:"65%",
        borderWidth:2,
        marginTop:20,
        alignSelf:'center',
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    submitButton: {
        marginTop:10,
        width:"40%",
        alignSelf:'center',
        height:35,
        backgroundColor:"#948521",
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    submitText: {
        padding:5,
        alignSelf:'center',
        textAlign:'center',
        fontSize:20
    },
    storyButton: {
        width:"100%",
        height:60,
        alignContent:'center',
        textAlign:'center',
        backgroundColor:'#48bfe3',
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginTop:20
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:'bold'
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling setState from the render method will lead to memory leak, infinite loop, it's a big red flag.

Rather you should try to use setInterval and clearInterval if you want the library of stories should keep updating with in given interval.

```
this.inetervalId = null;

componentDidMount(){
this.inetervalId = setInterval(()=> { this.displayStories() }, 3 * 1000)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
if(this.intervalId){clearInterval(this.intervalId)}
}
```

For every 3 second the interval will be triggered and this.displayStories will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using getDerivedStateFromProps() lifecycle method, its invoked after a component is instantiated as well as before it is re-rendered. It can return an object to update state, or null to indicate that the new props do not require any state updates.

Answer (score 0):

### Why?

You can’t update the state inside the `render` method because you try to update the *state* before return its JSX **initially** (that means it still not mounted as mentioned in the error). Check below the sample code snippet.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
       test: false
    }
  }

  render() {
     this.setState({
       test: true
     }); // Runs First

     return <div>This JSX returns after setState. That means you're trying to update a state of an unmounted component.</div>
  }
}
```

Check this comprehensive graph on **React Method Execution Order** for better understanding.

[image]

Resource - https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

### What to do?

You can use `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods to handle these kinds of scenarios.

But after considering your requirement it’s best if you can use **Context** in React. Update your context when somebody adds a story. It will simplify your application logic also.

Guide on Context - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html